# Dependency injection with @WebServiceRef I'm doing it wrong. But how?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, apache-tomee

I'm getting an exception while trying to inject a webservice that's completely separate from my JVM.

My environment is TomEE v1.0.0, which is a JEE6 webprofile container.

ThemeQueryService is a JAXWS annotated interface.

```
@SessionScoped 
@Named("managedBeanMB") 
public class ManagedBeanMB implements Serializable { 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

        @WebServiceRef(
            wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8777/services/queryService?wsdl") 
        private QueryService queryService; 
.... 
}
```

Later on, I get an NPE when trying to use the injected service:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.JaxWsServiceReference.getObject(JaxWsServiceReference.java:73) 
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:173) 
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiResourceInjectionService.lookup(CdiResourceInjectionService.java:134) 
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiResourceInjectionService.fillInjectionProperties(CdiResourceInjectionService.java:112) 
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiResourceInjectionService.injectJavaEEResources(CdiResourceInjectionService.java:96) 
        at org.apache.webbeans.component.AbstractInjectionTargetBean.injectResources(AbstractInjectionTargetBean.java:432) 
        at org.apache.webbeans.portable.creation.InjectionTargetProducer.inject(InjectionTargetProducer.java:91) 
        at org.apache.webbeans.component.InjectionTargetWrapper.inject(InjectionTargetWrapper.java:79) 
        at org.apache.webbeans.component.AbstractOwbBean.create(AbstractOwbBean.java:182)
```

I get the feeling I don't understand WebServiceRef... Is it used for JNDI transport only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use TomEE+, not the TomEE (webprofile).

See here: http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/JEE-Dependency-Injection-failure-on-WebServiceRef-results-in-bizzare-NullPointerException-td4656360.html#a4656377